# net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException

Tags: java, flutter, dart, android-studio, gradle

The error is occuring in the project when i tried to run it please help me regarding the project your support is well appritiacted i am unable to understand and deliver the solution for this error

The Error:

```
Error while receiving file changes
net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Error received when handling events, error = 1: D:\Yash Workspace\Edigi Solutions Nashik\EduOmega\android
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.executeRunLoop0(Native Method)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher.access$100(AbstractFileEventFunctions.java:159)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.AbstractFileEventFunctions$NativeFileWatcher$1.run(AbstractFileEventFunctions.java:173)
Stopping file watching and invalidating VFS after an error happened

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' (type 'FlutterTask').
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assetsDirectory' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'buildMode' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'fastStart' doesn't have a configured value.

    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Assign a value to 'fastStart'.
      2. Mark property 'fastStart' as optional.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'flutterExecutable' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I had tried various gradle fixes like tried deleting `.gradle` folder and deleting `pubspec.lock` and doing `Pub get` but it didn't solved the error.